# No muestra los resultados de una tabla específica

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

[image: Ejmplo]

Tengo mi sistema creado, pero en sistemas no muestra los datos de una tabla cuando stp.deposito_id = '25', cuando es cualquier otro depósito me muestra los datos que contenga ese depósito, en caso contrario me muestra el mensaje
"No se encontraron registros".

La cadena que obtengo al usar el var_dump y al ejecutarla en Workbench me muestra los datos, pero en el sistema no.

ACLARACIÓN: Como se muestra en la imagen me tendrian que salir los datos, ese es otro depósito que si muestra. El depósito que a mi no me muestra es Ciudad Gamma.

query($sql);

    while ($dato = $res->fetch_object()) {
        $total += $dato->Precio * $dato->cantidad_existente;
    }

    return $total;
}

function Retornar_Nombre_Deposito($id) {
    global $mysqli;

    $sql = "SELECT nombre FROM obrasdeposito WHERE id = '$id'";
    $res = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $obj = $res->fetch_object();

    return $obj->nombre;
}
?>

    
        
        
        
        
        
            .legend { width: 2%; border: 1px solid #999; text-align: center; padding: 2px; display: inline-block; }
            .right { text-align: right !important; }
        
        
        
        
    
    
        
        
            
                
            
        
        
            
                
                    
                
            
        
        
            
                **Depósito**
                
            
            
                **Legenda**
                
                    A
                    B
                    C

```
<table class="table-list">
            <thead>
                <tr> 
                    <td>C&oacute;digo Art&iacute;culo</td>
                    <td>Nombre Art&iacute;culo</td>
                    <td>Stock Actual * Precio</td>
                    <td>Unidad</td>
                    <td>%</td>
                    <td>Acumulado</td>
                    <td>Categor&iacute;a</td> 
                    <td>Stock Actual</td>
                    <td>Precio</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                $sql = "SELECT 
                            res.codigoArticulo, 
                            res.articulo, 
                            res.unidad, 
                            res.Precio, 
                            res.cantidad_existente 
                        FROM
                            (
                                SELECT 
                                    stp.cod_articulo as codigoArticulo,
                                    art.nombre as articulo,
                                    stp.stock as cantidad_existente,
                                    art.unidad as unidad,
                                    IFNULL(ROUND((
                                        SELECT dp.precio
                                        FROM detalle_pedidos as dp
                                        INNER JOIN pedidos p ON p.num_pedido = dp.num_pedido
                                        WHERE p.estado != 'ANULADA' AND dp.cod_articulo = stp.cod_articulo
                                        ORDER BY dp.num_pedido DESC
                                        LIMIT 1
                                    ), 2), 0) as Precio
                                FROM
                                    stock_tareaprogramada as stp
                                INNER JOIN 
                                    articulos as art ON stp.cod_articulo = art.cod_articulo 
                                WHERE
                                    stp.deposito_id = '{$_POST['deposito']}'
                                    AND stp.cod_articulo = art.cod_articulo
                                    AND stp.stock > 0
                                    AND art.estado != 'BAJA'
                                    AND art.stockeable = 'SI'
                            ) as res
                        ORDER BY res.Precio * res.cantidad_existente DESC";
/*var_dump($sql)*/
                $res = $mysqli->query($sql);

                if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
                    $total = Retornar_Total($sql);
------------------------------------------------------------

                    while ($dato = $res->fetch_object()) {
                        $cantidadPorPrecio = $dato->cantidad_existente * $dato->Precio;
                        $porcentaje = ($cantidadPorPrecio * 100) / $total;
                        $acumulado = $acumulado + $porcentaje;

                        if ($acumulado < 80 ) {
                            $categoria = "A";
                            $bgcolor = "#BEF781";
                        } elseif ($acumulado < 95 ) {
                            $categoria = "B";
                            $bgcolor = "#F3E2A9";
                        } else {
                            $categoria = "C";
                            $bgcolor = "#FA5882";
                        }
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo "[" . $dato->codigoArticulo. "]" ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $dato->articulo ?></td>
                            <td class="right"><?php echo number_format($cantidadPorPrecio, 2, ",", ".") ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $dato->unidad ?></td>
                            <td class="right"><?php echo "%" . number_format($porcentaje, 2, ',' , ".") ?></td>    
                            <td class="right"><?php echo "%" . number_format($acumulado, 2, ',' , '.') ?></td>
                            <td bgcolor="<?php echo $bgcolor ?>"><?php echo $categoria ?></td>
                            <td class="right"><?php echo number_format($dato->cantidad_existente, 2, ",", ".") ?></td>
                            <td class="right"><?php echo number_format($dato->Precio, 2, ",", ".") ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?
                    }
------------------------------------------------------------
                } else {
                    ?>
                    <tr class="tr-no-data">
                        <td colspan="9">No se encontraron registros.</td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>TOTAL</strong></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="right"><?php echo number_format($total, 2, ",", ".") ?></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="right"><?php echo "%" . number_format($acumulado, 2, ",", ".") ?></td>
                    <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="9" style="text-align:right"><strong>Cantidad de Resultados:</strong> <?php echo $res->num_rows ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="9" style="text-align:right"><strong>Fecha de Emisi&oacute;n:</strong> <?php echo date("d/m/Y h:m:s") ?></td>
                </tr>




            </tfoot>
        </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow. El que el `var_dump` muestre algo no significa que la consulta funcione o traiga datos, pues haces `var_dump` de la variable `$sql` que no es otra cosa que una cadena. Los datos, en caso de que haya algunos, estarían en `$res`, no en `$sql`. Además, tienes una función `Retornar_Total` que no se sabe lo que hace. ¿Qué muestra un `var_dump($res);`? Eso es lo 1º que deberías probar.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/29967/a-cedano Si, perdón me expliqué. Se para que sirve el var_dump, lo que quise decir es que con la cadena que obtuve a través de la función la ejecute en el workbench y me devolvió los datos.  De igual formas, creo que el error que tengo en mi código es otro, porque cuando selecciono cualquier otro [deposito] de mi base de datos, en el sistema si me muestra los datos.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/29967/a-cedano Ahi subi todo el código y creo que mejor explicado, perdón por subir todo desordenado e incompleto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sí alguien alguna vez tiene el mismo problema, la solución que encontré fue agregar al inicio del código(después de abrir php), lo siguiente:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('max_execution_time',300);
```

Es decir, el problema que había era el tiempo de ejecución ya que era muy pesada la tabla.